# permission level on a machine to develop sp 2010 using visual studio and SP 2010 designer

Tags: sharepoint-2010, system-requirements

here is the scenario:
We will be moving the development environment from servers to our local machines.  Our local machines will have SQL server, SP 2010 server, SP 2010 designer, and Visual Studio 2010 on them.  I need some technical specs stating administrator permissions is required to perform development and debug tasks, do any exists?  i have been trying to find something on but have come up short.

Granted this is assuming admin permissions is required to perform these tasks, but i don't see how it wouldn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need administrative permissions on the local machine. For instance you need to run Visual Studio 2010 using elevated privilegies to be able to debug your solution and you need admin privs to be able to deploy farm solutions.

For sandboxed solutions, there is no need for admin privs though.

Comment: any MS articles proving this.  My asset management team wants proof.

Comment: Take a look at this installation guide: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee554869.aspx. You need administrator access to install it.

Comment: Not proof, but from experience, I can verify what Wictor has said.

Comment: yea the same here, but they are sticklers.  telling me they will install the apps, all i have to do is call.  thanks for all your answers.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly where it's documented but as I said: you need admin to 1) debug SP/ASP.NET/IIS, 2) deploy farm solutions. Best way is to let them do it for you - then you call them every 5 minutes when you need help with admin tasks. It will only take half an hour and you'll get admin privs.